# Spring security PreAuthentication Filter asks for AuthenticationEntryPoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, siteminder, pre-authentication

I am trying to use PreAuthFilter (for Siteminder) with Spring Security 3.0.

```xml
 <http  use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/403.jsp" access="permitAll" />
        <!-- Allow non-secure access to static resources  -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" filters="none" />

        <custom-filter ref="siteminderFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>

<!--        <form-login  /> -->
        <logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp"/>
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="siteminderFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="principalRequestHeader" value="SM_USER"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="exceptionIfHeaderMissing" value="false"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="AdminUserDetailsService" class="com.fw.security.auth.MyUserDetailsService">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
            <beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
                <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="AdminUserDetailsService"/>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <authentication-provider ref="preauthAuthProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>
```

Above configuration fails with

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: No AuthenticationEntryPoint could be established. Please make sure you have a login mechanism configured through the namespace (such as form-login) or specify a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint with the 'entry-point-ref' attribute 
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-app-context.xml]
```

1) How do I specify an AuthenticationEntryPoint???

2) And is it really applicable for a PreAuthentication scenario???

### Solution

as per axtavt's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009834/spring-security-preauthentication-filter-asks-for-authenticationentrypoint/8010784#8010784) below:

Create a bean with Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint

```xml
<beans:bean id="http403EntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint">
    </beans:bean>
```

and refer it in <http>

```xml
<http  use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint">
```

Comment: Although this is a comment to thanks, thank you very much for completing axtavt's answer with the actual configuration xml! VERY useful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I guess in the case of pre-authentication you need to declare an [`Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint.html) and reference it via `entry-point-ref` attribute of `<http>`.